# woocommerce checkout page keeps loading

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I try to checkout the purchase it keeps loading all the day. I've checked the console but there is no error. I don't know what's causing this. [here is the website link](https://thenanoils.com/). I'm new to woocommerce. Kindly help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the loading problem is due to a theme or woocommerce.

To figure out what's wrong, allow debugging in WordPress and look at the debug log to see what's wrong.

To enable debugging in WordPress, go to this link. = https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Then disable your all plugins excluding woocommerceand then check error is occurred or not, if loading is stoped then enable one by one all plugins and check which one is faulty for this error..

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in **Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS or SiteOrigin CSS**

```css
.blockOverlay{
    display: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This occurs due to many reasons just you can resolve by
Sol1: **AJAX error due to WordPress settings**
The URL’s in Settings > General need to match – this is because AJAX requests don’t work across different domains
[image: check this]

Sol2: **WP Memory Limit**

We recommend at least 64MB. See: [Increasing the WP Memory Limit](http://docs.woocommerce.com/document/increasing-the-wordpress-memory-limit/)

Comment: tried everything you said and it didn't work :(